# awk string replacement - properly escape '&' character

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am working on one of our applications to update the docker image from using static configs for each environment to a single template using dynamic variable insertion with awk. Our Dockerfile calls a script that echoes out each variable pulled from a file called values.yaml, then uses awk to go replace each occurrence of the variable name in a template.conf file with its value in the yaml file. It works nicely except for one variable that contains '&' in the value. Here's a basic layout:

script.sh:

```bash
echo '***DEBUG***'
echo MY_VAR - ${MY_VAR}
echo '***END DEBUG***'

#Insert variable
awk -i inplace '{ gsub(/MY_VAR/, ENVIRON["MY_VAR"]); print }' template.conf
```

values.yaml:

```yaml
envvars:
  MY_VAR: "foo&bar"
```

template.conf:

```
Sometext: MY_VAR
```

Output:

```
***DEBUG***
MY_VAR - foo&bar
***END DEBUG***

Sometext: fooMY_VARbar
```

I hope that's clear enough to illustrate my problem. I understand the cause is that awk is interpreting the '&' character as metadata, rather than a literal character, and so it substitutes the name of the variable where the character is located. What I can't figure out is how to stop that from happening. I have tried the following alternate awk commands, neither of which seemed to make a difference:

`awk -i inplace '{ gsub(/MY_VAR/, gensub(/&/, "\\&", "g", ENVIRON["MY_VAR"])) }; { print }' template.conf`

`awk -i inplace '{ gsub("MY_VAR", ENVIRON["MY_VAR"]); print }' template.conf`

I searched the forums for a bit but didn't find anything about this specific problem, so I apologize if this turns out to be a duplicate.

Comment: Perl to the rescue! `perl -pe 's/MY_VAR/$ENV{MY_VAR}/g'`. Otherwise, you have to escape the special characters in the variable before running awk, e.g. `MY_VAR=${MY_VAR//&/\\&}`.

Comment: @choroba you are my hero. If you repost this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted! That worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/MY_VAR/$ENV{MY_VAR}/g'
```

Otherwise, you have to escape the special characters in the variable before running awk, e.g.

```
MY_VAR=${MY_VAR//&/\\&}
```

Note that there might be more characters to escape than just `&`.